# Is it dangerous using HTTP Basic Authentication and storing usename/password in local storage for future requests? (without XSS)

Tags: javascript, xss, basic-authentication

I'm developing an app in React and Spring Boot + Spring Security. Right now, I've added HTTP Basic Auth for user authentication. The user inputs username and password in a login form, and I send them (of course over HTTPS) to my backend. If the user is authenticated, I send back success, and the frontend saves the credentials into local storage for future requests (i.e. no session server-side). Then whenever I navigate to a "secured" route in React, I check the local storage, and then use the credentials for my secured requests. When the user needs to logout, the app removes the credentials from local storage.

It's a very trivial security implementation, but unless I have XSS vulnerability, or there is downgrade to HTTP (for my domain, not possible - HSTS preloading), I don't think it's vulnerable. But the main problem I see with it is that I can't for example logout users remotely, which might come in handy at some point. Have I found myself in a dead-end? Is HTTP Basic Auth just not meant for stateless authentication with SPAs?

Comment: unsure why you would be saving user credentials into localstorage. Hopefully it is not plain text.

Comment: HTTPS is still vulnerable to MITM attacks

Comment: if you're not gonna use a server session, then it would be better to use JWT tokens

Comment: @IłyaBursov How would https be vulnerable to MITM attacks? Assuming that the browser validates the server's certificate, of course.

Comment: @Thomas via proxy, which can issue forged certificates, see details https://security.stackexchange.com/a/67534

Comment: @IłyaBursov I quote: "Provided that the client trusts this CA". It shouldn't. This is why browsers and operating systems ship with built-in stores of trusted certificates. They won't normally trust any root cert from some random proxy server unless the user has deliberately added it.

Comment: @Thomas right, but there are many ways to trick user and install some CA as trusted one, I'm not saying it easy, but it is possible, and just having HTTPS is not 100% safe

Comment: @IłyaBursov Yeah, of course if the user has installed untrusted CA, than all bets are off.

Comment: @NeilMcGuigan I'm not sure about JWT specifically, because of its other issues like complicated revocation logic, and basically reimplementing sessions with it, which I often read about. I might just go back to stateful backend, that sends back a session cookie.

Comment: @mlukas MITM can work even without trusted CA, it can intercept response from your server with HSTS header and just remove it and return redirect to http to client, while maintaining valid https session internally, so client will work with http site (of course it should be first visit to site and site should not be in browser's preload list)

Comment: @mlukas you're really gonna bog down your server by authenticating on every request, especially if you're using BCrypt, which you should

Comment: @NeilMcGuigan I am using bcrypt. Right now, with the basic auth, you're probably right. But what if I choose to return to stateful backend with session cookie? Is that still more resource intensive than JWT tokens?

Comment: @IłyaBursov Oh, that's also an interesting point. I don't think it applies here, because of the domain I'm using (.app), which should be in the preload list. But that's good to know for one's that are not on that list.

Comment: @mlukas it is possible to remove subdomain from preload list, so nothing is safe

Comment: @IłyaBursov I'm guessing you mean, the same way how it's possible to bypass HTTPS via proxy? Makes sense.. if untrusted CA is installed into someone's browser to bypass HTTPS, they might as well change the HSTS preload list.

Comment: @mlukas no, I mean https://hstspreload.org/removal/

Comment: @IłyaBursov Also regarding the MITM, downgrading to HTTP... it seems like there's no way to really login to a website without being 100% secure no? Either I protect my website well, and don't have any XSS vulnerability, so I might as well store the password in local storage in plain text. Or I do have XSS, and I can't secure the input values in any way. The client either connects with a proper HTTPS (enforced by HSTS preloading), or he's compromised, and nothing will help. Basically, I can't be alone in trying to provide a secure site. The client side has to also do things right.

Comment: @mlukas there are many attack vectors, compromised client is very wide term, client can have keylogger installed, or use clean pc but be behind corporate firewall which is controlled by corrupt IT department, or it could be vulnerability in ISP's router, anyway my main point was - it is impossible to protect against everything, but storing clear text user/pass will not make hacker's life harder

Answer (score 1):

First, I would suggest not doing that. As you said, a downgrade to HTTP will expose credentials and a XSS vulnerability will make it possible for the attacker to steal the credentials of your users.

However, if you insist to store credentials in localStorage then you should ensure several things:

- Credentials should be encrypted in localStorage, and your application (server side) will decrypt them and only then "use the credentials for your secured requests".

This way, a downgrade to HTTP will expose the traffic but the credentials are transferred after encryption.

- Be extra-sensitive for XSS vulnerabilities and sanitize any user input (best practice regardless, but now the stakes are high). Stealing a session is different from stealing users' credentials where an attacker can steal all of your users' passwords over time, and execute a massive attack coming as legitimate requests from your users. This is in contrast to sessions with a timeout.

The localStorage is only accessible via scripts coming in through your own domain, so you're safe as long as the only frontend code running is your own.
But if any other code is executed, via injection or if you share the domain with someone else, they will be able to access the localStorage data.

For the second part of your question, logging out users remotely. You can implement it in a different way:

Upon a successful login, generate a completely random string unrelated to user credentials and store that in the database, along with an expiry date. Then, pass that string to be stored in localStorage.

From then on, so long as that local storage credential matches the database one and the timeout has not expired, you automatically consider them logged in.

This way, there is no risk concerning the exposure of the user's credentials from localStorage. However, with this temporary unique string essentially functioning as a sessionID, you will still to need to be aware of and take precautions against the risks associated with session hijacking.

Now, to end a user's session remotely, you can update the expiry date of that entry in the DB.

Comment: This sounds like I'd just be reinventing the default behavior of Spring Security, using JSESSIONID HttpOnly secure cookie. Which I'll probably do in the end. With React, I think input sanitation is not a problem, and neither is it in Spring controllers / JPA repositories.